# Como contar os emails repetidos em uma tabela Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabela onde alguns cadastros foram feitos usando os mesmos email. Gostaria de contabilizar esses emails repetidos, para isso estou usando dessa forma:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT email) AS Contar FROM cadastro;
```

O que estou achando estranho, é a quantidade retornado e por isso estou inseguro de usar essa query. Gostaria que retornasse:

> Existem 110 emails repetidos

Comment: E qual foi o retorno obtido?

Comment: Então.. ele está me retornando muitos cadastros, o valor é: 6050 e o cadastro tem 7543. Estou achando muito email repetido.

Comment: Sim, o que você está calculando são e-mails distintos, pois utilizou `DISTINCT`. A diferença desse valor para o total são de e-mails repetidos.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss isso só será verdade se um email não repetir mais de uma vez.

Comment: @rLinhares Se eu tenho os registros (a, a, a, a, b, c, c) o resultado com DISTINCT será 3, pois há 3 valores distintos, enquanto o total é 7, indicando que há 4 registros repetidos (3 a e 1 c)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss tens razão! confundi as bolas mas já me achei =p sorry (inclusive corrigi minha resposta - espero ter corrigdo certo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você deseja apenas listar os repetidos utilize a cláusula HAVING:

```
SELECT email, COUNT(*) FROM cadastro 
GROUP BY email
HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1);
```

Comment: Ola anonimo, na verdade nao preciso listar e sim trazer o total.

Comment: Mas a query acima fornece para cada email repetido a quantidade de repetições deste email existente no cadastro.

Answer (score 3):

Crie uma subconsulta pra saber os emails que se repetem:

```
SELECT COUNT(qtd)
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS qtd FROM cadastro GROUP BY email HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) as TB_TESTE
```

[teste executando](https://rextester.com/HDWA3185)

Comment: Olá rLinhares. Tentei seu código, mas deu esse erro: `Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a '*) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS qtd FROM cadastro GROUP BY email HAVING COUNT(*) > 1' na linha 1`

Comment: @Fox.11 resposta corrigida! além do erro de sintaxe percebi que deveria usar `count` ao invés do `sum` =p vou adicionar um _fiddle_ também.